# Python urlencode special character

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, python-2.x, urlencode

I have this variable here

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8') 
foo = u'"Esp\xc3\xadrito"'
```

which translates to "Espírito". But when I pass my variable to urlencode like this

```
urllib.urlencode({"q": foo}) # q=%22Esp%C3%83%C2%ADrito%22'
```

The special character is being "represented" wrongly in the URL.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Is this Python2 or 3?

Comment: @IronFist Python2. The function is called `urllib.parse.urlencode` in Python 3.

Comment: Yes its Python 2.7. Any idea what went wrong? When I put the q=%22Esp%C3%83%C2%ADrito%22' on decoder such as http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ the decoded value becomes q="EspÃ­rito"' which is wrong.

Comment: Are u saying *wrong* because of the percentage representation or because not actual encoding?

Comment: I wanted to send "Espírito" as a query parameter to an endoint but after I urlencode it, it becomes "EspÃ­rito". The "i" becomes "A" which is unintended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the wrong encoding of `"Espírito"`, I don't know where you get that, but this is the right one:

```
>>> s = u'"Espírito"'
>>> 
>>> s
u'"Esp\xedrito"'
```

Then encoding your query:

```
>>> u.urlencode({'q':s.encode('utf-8')})
'q=%22Esp%C3%ADrito%22'
```

This should give you back the right encoding of your string.

EDIT: This is regarding right encoding of your query string, demo:

```
>>> s = u'"Espírito"'
>>> print s
"Espírito"
>>> s.encode('utf-8')
'"Esp\xc3\xadrito"'
>>> s.encode('latin-1')
'"Esp\xedrito"'
>>> 
>>> print "Esp\xc3\xadrito"
EspÃ­­rito
>>> print "Esp\xedrito"
Espírito
```

This clearly shows that the right encoding for your string is ***most probably*** `latin-1` (even `cp1252` works as well), now as far as I understand, `urlparse.parse_qs` either assumes default encoding `utf-8` or your system default encoding, which as per your post, you set it to `utf-8` as well.

Interestingly, I was *playing* with the query you provided in your comment, I got this:

```
>>> q = "q=Esp%C3%ADrito"
>>> 
>>> p = urlparse.parse_qs(q)
>>> p['q'][0].decode('utf-8')
u'Esp\xedrito'
>>>
>>> p['q'][0].decode('latin-1')
u'Esp\xc3\xadrito'

#Clearly not ASCII encoding.
>>> p['q'][0].decode()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#320>", line 1, in <module>
    p['q'][0].decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> 
>>> p['q'][0]
'Esp\xc3\xadrito'
>>> print p['q'][0]
EspÃ­rito
>>> print p['q'][0].decode('utf-8')
Espírito
```

Comment: But according http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=string-literal \xc3\xad is indeed "í"

Comment: Sorry I should've explained it clearer regarding how I get the \xc3\xad. Its a pipeline of microservices and in fact first I got "q=Esp%C3%ADrito" (urlencoded) then I ran urlparse.parse_qs on it then I get u'"Esp\xc3\xadrito"'

Comment: Anyway I think its my Python problem, when I run s = u'"Espírito"' then s on interactive mode I get u'"Esp\xc3\xadrito"' instead of u'"Esp\xedrito"' like you did.

Comment: Probably, it needs more investigation on how `urlparse` handles unicode queries, from where it gets the encoding scheme, I tried to look into `urlparse` documentation, but did not find any lead.

Comment: Just to be perfectly candid, `u"Esp\u00edrito"` is the correct way to encode this string.  You can't meaningfully use UTF-8 in a `u"..."` string; these strings are by definition Unicode and cannot accommodate any other encoding (though you see people work around this fact in creative ways sometimes for various reasons).  A *byte string* in UTF-8 can be converted to a Unicode string, and vice versa, but they are two different representations which you seem to have confused.

Comment: The fact that `b'"Esp\xedrito"` yields the output you expect *if and only if* your encoding is Latin-1 is largely coincidental.  It's convenient but sometimes confusing that Unicode and Latin-1 use the same code points in the range 128 to 255.

Comment: @tripleee, How did u know that your provided encoding is the right one?, I'm very confused here with the encoding scheme !

Comment: You'll probably want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Answer (score 0):

`urllib` and `urlparse` appear to work with byte string in Python 2. To get unicode strings, encode and decode using utf-8.

Here's an example of a round-trip:

```
data = { 'q': u'Espírito'}

# to query string:
bdata = {k: v.encode('utf-8') for k, v in data.iteritems()}
qs = urllib.urlencode(bdata)

# qs = 'q=Esp%C3%ADrito'

# to dict:
bdata = urlparse.parse_qs(qs)
data = { k: map(lambda s: s.decode('utf-8'), v)
            for k, v in bdata.iteritems() }

# data = {'q': [u'Espídrito']}
```

Note the different meaning of escape sequences: in `'Esp\xc3\xadrito'` (a string), they represent bytes, while in `u'"Esp\xedrito"'` (a unicode object) they represent Unicode code points.